# Scale the entire body when resize the browser screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a website that is not responsive , but if the windows is resize, everything is scale up / down , and keep the same ratio. It doesn't matter if the words are too small in small screen

I have tried using:

```
<meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1s.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).resize(function () {
      calculateNewScale();
    });

    calculateNewScale(); // if the user go to the page and his window is less than 1920px

    function calculateNewScale() {
      var percentageOn1 = $(window).width() / 1920;    
      $("body").css({
        "-moz-transform": "scale(" + percentageOn1 + ")",
        "-webkit-transform": "scale(" + percentageOn1 + ")",
        "transform": "scale(" + percentageOn1 + ")"
      });   
    }
  });
```

but the content seems still not to scale correctly.

The website is:

```
kotechweb.com/new_focus/page/about_us
```

Please have a look for reference, thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: you can use width:100vw and height:100vh to ensure they stay at the size of the browser

Comment: I think this approach works but you have a syntax error: `);` shouldn't be there. (line 82 in the original HTML).

Comment: Thanks , just updated the website css width:100vw and height:100vh on body and also fixed the jquery syntax,  but no luck as the element still overlap others when resize the windows, please have a look

Comment: create a MCVE. Your website is not a "legitimate" way of showing your problem, A. because it's not ***M***inimal and B. because hopefuly you'll solve your problem and then the question becomes worthless.